# Fast way to count duplicates in 30000 rows (Libreoffice Calc)

Tags: arrays, formatting, duplicates, conditional-statements, libreoffice-calc

Actually, I already have a partial answer!!! Conditional formatting with "Cell value is" -> "duplicate" !!! 
This way a check is performed for each user's new entry in "real time".

I need to check if duplicate entries exist in 30000 rows of a column (any value, but not blanks!) . I would like to keep track of how many duplicates during the filling process.

Ok, conditional formatting is a very effective visual indication and fast anough for my needs, but as I am not able to perform a loop to check the color of the cells (found some people against this approach!! Would be so easy! ) I need to find an alternative way to count the duplicates (as a whole, no need to identify how many for each case!).

I tryed the formula:

=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(F2:F30001;$F$2:$F$30001)>1))

It works, but it takes two minutes to finish.

If you want to replicate my case. My 30000 entries are formatted as: letter "A" and numbers between 100000 and 999999, e.g., A354125, A214547, etc. Copy as text the result of "=CONCATENATE("A";RANDBETWEEN(100000;999999))" to save time.

Thanks!

PS: Does anybody know the algorithm used to find the duplicates in conditional formatting (it is fast)?

A macro solution is not the best, but is acceptable!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(F2:F30001;$F$2:$F$30001)>1))` must do following: Count if `$F$2` is in `F2:F30001`, then count if `$F$3` is in `F2:F30001`, ..., then count if `$F$30001` is in `F2:F30001`. So it must fully loop over the array `F2:F30001` with each single item.

The fastest way counting duplicates in an array is avoiding fully loop over the array with each single item. One way is sorting first. There are very fast quick sort methods. Or using collections which per definition can only have unique items.

The following code uses the second way. The keys of a `Collection` must be unique. Adding an item having a duplicate key fails.

```
Public Function countDuplicates(vArray As Variant, Optional inclusive As Boolean ) As Variant
 On Error Goto wrong
 If IsMissing(inclusive) Then inclusive = False
 oDuplicatesCollection = new Collection
 oUniqueCollection = new Collection
 lCountAll = 0
 For Each vValue In vArray
  If contains(oUniqueCollection, CStr(vValue)) Then
   On Error Resume Next
    oDuplicatesCollection.Add 42, CStr(vValue)
   On Error Goto 0
  Else
   oUniqueCollection.Add 42, CStr(vValue)
  End If
  lCountAll = lCountAll + 1
 Next
 countDuplicates = lCountAll - oUniqueCollection.Count + IIF(inclusive, oDuplicatesCollection.Count, 0)
 Exit Function
wrong:
 'xray vArray
 countDuplicates = CVErr(123)
End Function

Function contains(oCollection As Collection, sKey As String)
 On Error Goto notContains
 oCollection.Item(sKey)
 contains = True
 Exit Function
notContains:
 contains = False
End Function
```

The function can be called:

```
=COUNTDUPLICATES(F2:F30001, TRUE())
```

This should return the same result as your

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(F2:F30001,$F$2:$F$30001)>1))
```

The optional second parameter `inclusive` means the count includes all the values which are present multiple times. For example `{A1, A2, A2, A2, A3}` contains 3 times `A2`. Counting inclusive means the count result will be 3. Counting not inclusive means the count result will be 2. There is 2 times `A2` as a duplicate.

As you see, the function contains much more information than only the count of the duplicates. The `oDuplicatesCollection` contains each duplicate item. The `oUniqueCollection` contains each unique item. So this code could also be used for getting all unique items or all duplicate items.